# Is compressive strain equal to streching strain?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science

The stress induced on a piece of material (like a rectangular beam) is defined as:

$$\sigma = E\epsilon$$
where $E$ is the elastic modulus and $\epsilon$ is the strain.

The strain on the other hand is defined as the ratio of the new length of the beam to the original length of the beam:

$$\epsilon = \frac{L}{L_{0}}$$

So, for example, if we were to stretch a beam to $1.5$ its original length, the strain would be $\epsilon = \frac{1.5L_{0}}{L_{0}}=1.5$ (let's imagine this would be a realistic situation).

But if we were to compress the beam to half its original length, the strain would now be $\epsilon = \frac{0.5L_{0}}{L_{0}}=0.5$.

I find this confusing: In both cases, the deformation of the beam is the same, but in the stretching case the stress would be much higher! It doesn't make sense to me. Why do we induce a much higher stress to the beam by stretching (rather than compressing it) even though the deformation of the beam is the same?

Comment: See [here](http://john.maloney.org/Papers/On%20strain%20(9-20-06).pdf) for the correct definitions of engineering strain and true strain. We would expect compression to correspond to a negative strain in either case.

Comment: Strain is not defined as new length / original length.  It is rather the change in length / original length.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. Stretch $\lambda$ is the ratio between length increments so for an undeformed part it would be close to 1, while the strain for an undeformed part would be close to zero. The stretch in both cases is:

$$\lambda_1 = \frac{\text{d}L_f}{\text{d}L_0} = 1.50, \qquad \lambda_2 =  \frac{\text{d}L_f}{\text{d}L_0} = 0.50$$

The true strain is given by the [finite strain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_strain_theory) and is equal to $\varepsilon = (\lambda^2-1)/2$:

$$\varepsilon_1 = 0.625, \qquad \varepsilon_2 = -0.375$$

For small strains (stretch close to one), the approximation $\lambda \approx 1+\varepsilon$ can be used, although in this case we are not in small strains and this approach is bad:

$$\varepsilon_1 \approx 0.500, \qquad \varepsilon_2 \approx -0.500$$

In the first case the strain is underestimated by 25% and in the second case it is overestimated by the same amount.